# Different class modes: conditional constructors/methods vs inheritance?

Tags: c++

I currently own a custom peripheral with 8 red lights (first byte), 8 switches (second byte), 4 push button and 4 green lights (third byte). Instead of having to manipulate the hardware with low level instructions each time, I decided to make a class specially for this. Within this class, I decided to create 3 possible modes the peripheral could adopt:

1- DEFAULT: each control is controlling the light above them; each light is then dependant to each control and thus their status can't be controlled by the program itself.

2- MAPPABLE : each control can now have a custom behavior; each light is then independant to each control and thus their status can be controlled by the program itself.

3- ANIMATION : each control is now disabled and you can choose in a wide variety of light animations.

These three modes are all stored in a Enum:

```
enum Mode { DEFAULT, MAPPABLE, ANIMATION };
```

Now here are my constructors:

```
ZeBox(Mode mode = DEFAULT);
ZeBox(std::bitset<4> lightsGreen, Mode mode = DEFAULT);
ZeBox(std::bitset<8> lightsRed, Mode mode = DEFAULT);
ZeBox(std::bitset<4> lightsGreen, std::bitset<8> lightsRed, Mode mode = DEFAULT);
```

The problem is as follow: if I decide to initialize lights' status, the mode **CAN'T** be DEFAULT, because like I said, lights status in DEFAULT mode are only dependant to controls, and not the program itself. However, the lights status in the two other modes (MAPPABLE and ANIMATION) **CAN** be both affected by the program.

This is the kind of thing that can be resolved by using inheritance (each mode/class, for instance 'DefaultZeBox', 'MappableZeBox' and 'AnimationZeBox', has a custom constructor with custom methods and they all derive from the base class 'ZeBox'), but there would be one problem: how would I be able to change the peripheral mode with a method? I know I could do it by simply use polymorphism and instantiate a new object each time, but I did this class to make it easy to newcomers and I wanted to make a method for that purpose (like 'SetMode(Mode new_mode)'). However, if I don't use inheritance, I would have to find a way to "enable/disable" methods depending on the mode you choose.

I would prefer to use inheritance, but I don't know how I would be able to change the mode with a method.

Any idea?

Comment: You may create specific method without exposing the mode in the parameter, something like `SetAnimationMode(std::bitset<4> lightsGreen)`. (and use some factory with explicit name in place of your constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class should define a behavior and according to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) should have only one reason to change.

Lets say you define a constructor that receives the mode. Then your class will have N reasons to changes (N being the number of modes)!

So i would go for the inheritance. But make sure to have a factory to create the correct implementation according to the chosen mode.

To change the mode in run time - read about the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)